# Auto-delete old emails on IMAP account

Tags: email, automation, imap

I have a mail account that receives and stores copies of receipts sent to customers making reservations.

As the account gets filled up over time, and as I have no interest in looking at the content and manually handle the mails, I need an automatic solution to log on and delete mails older than x days.

PHP scripting is not an option as my service provider do not allow script access to the mail server.

Any ideas for a (mail) service that can set up a rule to delete these automatically (without having me log in to their system)?

Comment: Most email clients have such a "auto delete old messages" feature. Can you or they just enable that feature on whatever client app they use to review their messages?

Comment: Have been in touch with them - they have no solution - have tried to convince them to upgrade their system but to no avail...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could not place a script accessing the mails on my domain. However, it turns out that they only blocked localhost access - but not external host access. Therefore, my answer to the solution was, in the end, a php script.

Thought I would share it for those interested.
Never found a service that could help me though.

**Script for auto deleting old mails:**

```
<?php

$del = new DateTime();
$del->modify('-1 month');

$mbox = imap_open("{imap.test.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX", "username", "password")
 or die("can't connect: " . imap_last_error());

$MC = imap_check($mbox);

// Fetch an overview for all messages in INBOX
$result = imap_fetch_overview($mbox,"1:{$MC->Nmsgs}",0);
foreach ($result as $overview) {
    $date = $overview->date;
    $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('D, d M Y H:i:s O', $date); 

    if($date<$del) {
        imap_delete($mbox,$overview->msgno);
    }
}   
imap_expunge($mbox);
imap_close($mbox);
?>
```